# How to detect the orientation of a PDF document in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, pdf, orientation

I am currently working for a simple PDF reader using CGPDFDocumnentRef. It is all fine when I try to render a Portrait PDF document.  But when I try to render one in Landscape, it shows a rotated PDF document. Of course when I view that landscape PDF file in the web browser of a pdf reader, it is a landscape one.

Is there any method in iPhone SDK that can detect the Orientation of a pdf document?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Xeron0719

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try to get the page size of your pdf and then check if width is > than heigh and eventually rotate it...

```
-(CGSize)getPdfSize{
    CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("aPdfFile.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
    CGRect appR = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect (page, 1);
//  NSLog(@"          .....     pdf width: %f", appR.size.width); 
    return appR.size;
}
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks for the help. :)