# PDF-Scrollview - show PDF - document in landscape format

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiscrollview, orientation

I'm using Apple's example «PDFScrollView» to display PDFs on an iPad. This works fine, as long as the PDF-document is in Portrait-Mode.
When the document is in Landscape-mode, though, the document is always shown rotated by 90 degrees. 
I found this [How to detect the orientation of a PDF document in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321772/how-to-detect-the-orientation-of-a-pdf-document-in-iphone-sdk) - but when I try to get the dimensions of the PDF, the height is always bigger than the width, no matter what orientation the PDF has...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionend in, the `CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)` always returns the same size for a PDF, no matter what orientation the PDF has.

But the rotation of the page is returned correctly.

So I get the rotation using this code:

```
rotate =  CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(page);
```

And then use the code below which I found here: http://ipdfdev.com/2011/03/23/display-a-pdf-page-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/

```
switch (rotate) {
        case 0:
            // Translate the origin of the coordinate system at the 
            // bottom left corner of the page rectangle.
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, cropBox.size.height);
            // Reverse the Y axis to grow from bottom to top.
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            break;
        case 90:
            // Reverse the Y axis to grow from bottom to top.
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            // Rotate the coordinate system.
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI / 2);
            break;
        case 180:
        case -180:
            // Reverse the Y axis to grow from bottom to top.
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            // Translate the origin of the coordinate system at the 
            // top right corner of the page rectangle.
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, cropBox.size.width, 0);
            // Rotate the coordinate system with 180 degrees.
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
            break;
        case 270:
        case -90:
            // Translate the origin of the coordinate system at the 
            // bottom right corner of the page rectangle.
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, cropBox.size.height, cropBox.size.width);
            // Rotate the coordinate system.
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 2);
            // Reverse the X axis.
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1, 1);
            break;
    }
```

Et voilà - the PDF is displayed in the right orientation

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this with assumption that your problem is about rotating document when user rotates device....
For that you have to redraw document in view. TO achieve that do following....

1. change frame of the view in which document is drawn, and CALayer(OR CATiledLayer) being used in that view in following method.
   `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`
2. Call setNeedsDisplay method of CATiledLayer after changing frame.
3. Then return YES in 
   `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`.

Above steps will redraw the document in new frame of you View accordingly so it will appear properly.

->IF your view is in full screen or then only step 2 ans 3 will be enough.

Post here if any further assistance is required....

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but your assumption is unfortunately wrong. The PDFs are saved in landscape, so no matter what orientation the device has, the document is displayed with a 90 deg rotation. When the PDF is loaded, it is initially displayed with this rotation and it stays that way, even when the device is rotated...

Comment: I apology for irrelevant answer. As per my information PDF documents are set of commands that draw graphics on context...so they do not have any concept of orientation. They will appear the way they are created. Now i can make one suggestion here. Provide user a button for rotating document if it is not properly displayed. When user clicks you can rotate it using CGAffineTransform. Visit this link for rotating you view. http://stackoverflow.com/q/356882/919049

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you are drawing PDFs yourself? You could use `QLPreviewController` on iOS 4.0 or later, and `UIDocumentInteractionController` for previous versions.

Comment: I have to admit, that I never heard of those two... Looks very promising at first glance - although I need some special stuff like Bookmarks, but that might work as well... Thanks!

Comment: OK - after looking at it, it's not really what I need. I need the ability to jump to specific pages in the document, set bookmarks for pages and so on... QLPreviewController doesn't provide any pagination or bookmarks, as far as I can see.