# How to detect the orientation of a PDF page in Swift with PDFKit IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit, ios-pdfkit

I'm trying to get the orientation property of a PDF document. The purpose is, I would like to add a button widget in a location that depends on the orientation of the PDF document.

For example:

```
     func openPDFDocument() {
            if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PDF document", withExtension: "pdf"),
               let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL),
               let page = document.page(at: 0) {
                // Set our document to the view, center it, and set a background color
                pdfView?.document = document
                pdfView?.autoScales = true
                pdfView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                
              //I think I should be able to add a code here like:
              if page.orientation = Horizontal {
                self.insertResetButtonInto(page)
                } else {
//do nothing or do something else
                }     
        }
    }
```

This is the function I would like to add in case the document is in Landscape mode:

```
  func insertResetButtonInto(_ page: PDFPage) {

        let pageBounds = page.bounds(for: .cropBox)

        let resetButtonBounds = CGRect(x: 90, y: pageBounds.size.height - 300, width: 106, height: 32)
        let resetButton = PDFAnnotation(bounds: resetButtonBounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget.rawValue), withProperties: nil)
        resetButton.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.button.rawValue)
        resetButton.widgetControlType = .pushButtonControl
        resetButton.caption = "Reset"
        page.addAnnotation(resetButton)
        // Create PDFActionResetForm action to clear form fields.
        let resetFormAction = PDFActionResetForm()         
        resetFormAction.fieldsIncludedAreCleared = false
        resetButton.action = resetFormAction
  
    }
```

I got the example project from [Apple's documentation website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdf_widgets). I looked at a [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321772/how-to-detect-the-orientation-of-a-pdf-document-in-iphone-sdk), however it seems this was in Objective C.

I would appreciate the help in this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct API to get the `orientation` from a `PDFPage`. But you can first get the page size from `.mediaBox`, then calculate the orientation like below.

```
    let pageSize = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox).size
    
    if pageSize.width > pageSize.height {
        //landscape
    } else {
        //portrait
    }
```

Comment: I have a PDF document which is portrait, but width > height. Another one (from the same PDF "engine") is landscape, but width is also > height. How can I catch this?

Comment: I found it. `page.rotation` does the job. In my case, it shows 0 for portrait and 270 for landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I use another way to get the orientation of my pdf page.

```
func IsLandscape(page: PDFPage) -> Bool {
    let pointZero = pdfView.convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), from: page)
    let pointTen = pdfView.convert(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), from: page)
    let caculate = pointTen.x - pointZero.x
    print("pointZero: \(pointZero), pointTen:\(pointTen)")
    if (caculate > 0) {
        print("landscape")
        return true
    }
    else {
        print("portrait")
        return false
    }
}
```